# change the On_press color of button in KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

[image]

The above is the button color when the button is pressed.

In .kv file, i gave # Just for an example

```
Button:
                text:"Click here to print Hello world  "
                size_hint:[.9, .1]
                on_press: print("Hello world")
```

What should i do to change the on_press color of the button?

It is requested that the changes are in .kv file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `background_down` property of `Button` to set the background color of a `Button` when it is pressed. Unfortunately, the `background_down` must be an image, not a color tuple. But the image itself can be just a 1 pixel by 1 pixel image. For example, using a 1 pixel by 1 pixel image named `red.png` as the `background_down`:

```
Button:
    text:"Click here to print Hello world  "
    size_hint:[.9, .1]
    on_press: print("Hello world")
    background_down: 'red.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the background_color method under the kivy file.

Button:
text:"Click here to print Hello world  "
size_hint:[.9, .1]
on_press: print("Hello world")
background_color: 'red'
Goodday!